# Jboss 6 in Eclipse runtime installation configuration directory

Tags: jboss

I have an existing JBoss project on which I am working on.

Currently every time I make a change, even to a JSP file, I have to run an ANT build to make a EAR file and then import the file in JBoss localhost that I started from the command line.

I would like to run JBoss in Eclipse to make development easier.

I have installed JBoss Tools from Eclipse's Marketplace. However, when I try to install a runtime environment, I cannot get past the configuration screen. Even when I point the configuration directory to the directory with my standalone.xml.

[This is the picture of screen I cannot pass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7aRW.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your *New Server Runtime Environment* window, instead of selecting *JBoss 6.x Runtime* from the *JBoss Community* folder option, you should instead select the folder **Red Hat JBoss Middleware** and choose the **JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 6.1+ Runtime**:

[image: JBoss EAP runtime selection]

That's the runtime suited for JBoss EAP 6.4.0.

Afterwards you just need to set your *Home Directory* path.